# Getting selected value from datalist element

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create an autocomplete element for own purposes. Basically, my directive creates an input where I type my search and a datalist which will store my server values.

```
template: function (elem, attrs) {
    return '<input id="x" type="text" list="listing" /><datalist id="listing">' +
    '<option ng-repeat="item in resultFromServer"' +
    'label="myLabelValue" value="myTextValue" data-id="myIdValue" /></datalist>';
},
transclude: true,
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.children(0).bind('keyup', function () {
        var val = elem.children(0).val();
        var min = scope.$eval(attrs.minLength);

        if (val.length >= min) {
            doGetAsync(attrs.action, { searchFor: val }, function (result) {
                scope[resultFromServer] = result.Data;
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The research is working fine.

The issue is: how to fire an event when I select an `<option>` from that datalist? When I select any value from my `<datalist>`, I want to get that selected value and store the id into a scope variable. How can I do that?

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some text other than option in datalist, you can not have selection change type event in datalist.

You can bind "input" event on datalist, and on each input you can check input value with your list values. This way you can have your entered item id, item value, etc.

Comment: I tried all those approaches. None works properly for my case. That's a good solution, indeed. The solution I got was using a `<ul>` instead the `<datalist>` element and trigger some events on it. Thank you!